# Candidate expects 6 arguments, 0 provided

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am creating a QTableView formed of 6 columns that inserts specific values by calling a dialog. When I compile the project I receive the following errors in the file 'itemcameracalibrationdata.h':

note: candidate expects 6 arguments, 0 provided

note: candidate expects 6 arguments, 1 provided

For completeness I am including below both the 6 variables and the dialog file:
Below the **itemcalibrationdata.h**

```
#ifndef ITEMCAMERACALIBRATIONDATA_H
#define ITEMCAMERACALIBRATIONDATA_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>

class itemCameraCalibrationData
{
public:
    itemCameraCalibrationData(const QString &cameraName, const double fovx, const double fovy,
                              int version, const double focalLenghth,
                              const double reprojectionerror);

    QString cameraName() const { return mCameraName;}
    int version() const { return mVersion; }
    double fovx() const { return mFovx; }
    double fovy() const { return mFovy; }
    double focalLenghth() const { return mFocalLenghth; }
    double reprojectionerror() const { return mReprojectionError; }

private:
    QString mCameraName;
    int mVersion;
    double mFovx;
    double mFovy;
    double mFocalLenghth;
    double mReprojectionError;

};

#endif // ITEMCAMERACALIBRATIONDATA_H
```

Below the **itemcalibrationdata.cpp**

```
#include "itemcameracalibrationdata.h"

itemCameraCalibrationData::itemCameraCalibrationData(const QString &cameraName, const double fovx, const double fovy,
                                                     int version, const double focalLenghth,
                                                     const double reprojectionerror)
{
    mCameraName = cameraName;
    mFovx = fovx;
    mFovy = fovy;
    mVersion = version;
    mFocalLenghth = focalLenghth;
    mReprojectionError = reprojectionerror;
}
```

Then see the **cameracaldialog.cpp** and the error is in this file at the line **ui(new Ui::cameraCalDialog)**

```
#include "cameracaldialog.h"
#include "ui_cameracaldialog.h"
#include "itemcameracalibrationdata.h"

#include <QFile>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QCompleter>
#include <QFileSystemModel>

cameraCalDialog::cameraCalDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::cameraCalDialog)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);
}

cameraCalDialog::~cameraCalDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void cameraCalDialog::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    mItemCamCal = itemCameraCalibrationData(ui->camName_lineEdit->text(),
                                            ui->ver_lineEdit->text().toInt(),
                                            ui->fovx_lineEdit->text().toDouble(),
                                            ui->fovy_lineEdit->text().toDouble(),
                                            ui->focal_lineEdit->text().toDouble(),
                                            ui->rep_lineEdit->text().toDouble());
    accept();
}

void cameraCalDialog::on_buttonBox_rejected()
{
    rejected();
}
```

as last file the **cameracaldialog.h**

```
#ifndef CAMERACALDIALOG_H
#define CAMERACALDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include "itemcameracalibrationdata.h"


namespace Ui {
class cameraCalDialog;
}

class cameraCalDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit cameraCalDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~cameraCalDialog();
    itemCameraCalibrationData itemCamCal() const { return mItemCamCal; }


private slots:
    void on_buttonBox_accepted();
    void on_buttonBox_rejected();

private:
    Ui::cameraCalDialog *ui;
    itemCameraCalibrationData mItemCamCal;
};

#endif // CAMERACALDIALOG_H
```

Thank you very much for any insight you can provide on this matter

Comment: Advice -- You could have attempted a [mcve], such as [this one](https://www.ideone.com/BFZwwq).  See the issue now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use:

```
itemCameraCalibrationData mItemCamCal;
```

in the .h you are creating a new object, but the class `itemCameraCalibrationData` needs parameters, for that reason it throws the error.

In your case you do not want to create it in the .h but in the slot `on_buttonBox_accepted` so the solution is to declare a pointer in the .h and use `new` to create the object:

***.h**

```
class cameraCalDialog : public QDialog
{
    ...

private:
    Ui::cameraCalDialog *ui;
    itemCameraCalibrationData *mItemCamCal;
};
```

***.cpp**

```
cameraCalDialog::~cameraCalDialog()
{
    delete ui;
    delete mItemCamCal;
}


void cameraCalDialog::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    mItemCamCal = new itemCameraCalibrationData(ui->camName_lineEdit->text(),
                                            ui->ver_lineEdit->text().toInt(),
                                            ui->fovx_lineEdit->text().toDouble(),
                                            ui->fovy_lineEdit->text().toDouble(),
                                            ui->focal_lineEdit->text().toDouble(),
                                            ui->rep_lineEdit->text().toDouble());
    accept();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much eyllanesc. It is compiling and didn't realize about that! Thanks PaulMcKenzie for the documentation/source provided, they are very helpful.

Comment: @Emanuele Also, if you really wanted to instantiate the `itemCameraCalibrationData` with 6 parameters on construction of the `cameraDialog`, you would use the [member initialization list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list), i.e. `cameraDialog(QWidget *parent) : itemCameraCalibrationData(arg1, arg2, etc.) {}`

Comment: This answer suggests manual dynamic memory allocation, and associated indirection costs, as a fix for the missing default constructor...

Answer (score 1):

1. You need a default constructor.
2. Polluting the interface with `const` value parameters is pointless. The `const` belongs in the implementation, and yes, the signatures can differ that way. The language is designed that way on purpose.
3. Use initializer lists.

```
// itemcameracalibrationdata.cpp
#pragma once
#include <QString>

class itemCameraCalibrationData {
public:
    itemCameraCalibrationData() = default;
    itemCameraCalibrationData(const QString &cameraName, 
                              double fovx, double fovy,
                              int version, double focalLenghth,
                              double reprojectionerror);

    QString cameraName() const { return mCameraName;}
    int version() const { return mVersion; }
    double fovx() const { return mFovx; }
    double fovy() const { return mFovy; }
    double focalLenghth() const { return mFocalLenghth; }
    double reprojectionerror() const { return mReprojectionError; }
private:
    QString mCameraName;
    int mVersion = {};
    double mFovx = {};
    double mFovy = {};
    double mFocalLenghth = {};
    double mReprojectionError = {};
};
```

```
// itemcameracalibrationdata.cpp
#include "itemcameracalibrationdata.h"

itemCameraCalibrationData::itemCameraCalibrationData(
    const QString &cameraName, const double fovx, const double fovy,
    const int version, const double focalLenghth, const double reprojectionerror)
:
    mCameraName(cameraName),
    mFovx(fovx),
    mFovy(fovy),
    mVersion(version),
    mFocalLenghth(focalLenghth),
    mReprojectionError(reprojectionerror)
{}
```